How to avoid pandas to_parquet changing data type?
I have a dataframe which contains columns of type list. If I write this dataframe to parquet and read from it, it changes to numpy array. MWE:
home_directory = os.path.join(rf"C:\\Users\\{os.getlogin()}")
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_column': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]})
print(type(df['my_column'].iloc[0]))
df.to_parquet(os.path.join(home_directory,'data'), engine='pyarrow')
df_from_parquet = pd.read_parquet(os.path.join(home_directory,'data'), engine='pyarrow')
print(type(df_from_parquet['my_column'].iloc[0]))

Output:

<class 'list'>


<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Is there a way to maintain the list type?

Use engine='fastparquet' in your function calls.
example:
df.to_parquet(os.path.join(home_directory,'data'), engine='fastparquet')

and
pd.read_parquet(os.path.join(home_directory,'data'), engine="fastparquet")

It will give you the following output:

make sure to download fastparquet package using:
pip install fastparquet

I hope this helps!
